# ckEditor plugin replace SelectedBlocks text

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor-plugin

I have text in editor.

<p>string1</p>

<p>string2</p>

I want to create a plugin that will insert after the opening tag "!{" and before the closing "}!"

this is my plugin code

```
class StrTest extends Plugin {
    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;
        editor.ui.componentFactory.add('strTest', () => {
            const button = new ButtonView();
            button.set({
                label: '{}',
                withText: true
            });

            button.on('execute', () => {

                editor.model.change(writer => {
                    // editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks();
                    for (const block of editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks()) {
                        let child = block
                        // child.textNode.setText('New text content');
                        console.log(block)
                        console.log(block.getChild(0))
                        console.log(block.getChild(0).data)

                    }
                });
            });
            return button;
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone give an example of how to replace text in a tag?
I get a block, I get children and data, but I don’t understand how to replace the text.
Object field "data" is read only and have only getter.